# Rails: Tutorials on how to allow users to personnalize their stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm new to Rails (and web development in general). I've been searching for tutorials on Rails that can help me getting through a project. I've found a solution for almost all my question but one still remains.

As the title suggests, I want to enable users of my website to personnalize their css stylesheets for their personnal space. Twitter like.

Can anyone help me ? That's would be worderful.

Thanks !

EDIT:

Okay so here is my code so far (i'm using Devise)

```
#stylesheets_controller.rb
class StylesheetsController < ApplicationController

  def user_css
  if user_signed_in?
    @user = current_user
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.css
  end
end

end
```

My "dynamic" CSS:

```
#user_css.css.erb
<%=
  if @user # User log in ?
    background_color = @user.color_index
  else
    background_color = "666"
  end
%>

.cadre {
   background-color : #<%= background_color %>;
   height: 50 px;
   width: 50 px;
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong because I've got this error and can't load my CSS:

> Started GET "/stylesheets/user_css.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-18 15:09:07 +0200
>
> Processing by StylesheetsController#user_css as HTML
>
> ←[1m←[36mUser Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 5) LIMIT 1←[0m
>
> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 127ms

If you need the code from any of my files, please tell me.

Comment: just a heads up: be leery of css injection and design accordingly.  See [this Rails Guides Atricle](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#css-injection) for a basic introduction to CSS injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try creating a stylesheets controller:

```
class StylesheetsController < ...
  def per_user # or whatever name you like
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.css # I didn't try it, but I guess this should work, please tell me if not
    end
  end
end
```

And this is your template: /app/views/stylesheets/per_user.css.erb

```
/* put whatever you want here */
#user-<%= @user.id %> {
  color: #666;
}

<%= @user.user_defined_css %>
```

And finally the route:

```
get '/stylesheets/per_user.css' => 'stylesheets#per_user', :as => :per_user_stylesheet

<%= stylesheet_link_tag per_user_styleseet_path %>
```

I guess stylesheets won't change too frequent. So you would better cache the result.

=== UPDATED ===

I have tried the above code, it was not working also.......

So this is another way I can think of, by making use of partial.

In your layout file:

```
# views/layouts/application.html.erb
......
<head>
  <%= render :partial => "stylesheets/user_css", :locals => {:user => @user} %>
</head>
......
```

And your partial contains the customized css for the user.

This may not very beautiful, but I think this should work.

Comment: I've updated my original post, could you take a look at it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your new solution doesn't work: Missing partial stylesheets/user_css with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths. I've rename my "_user_css.css.erb" but it won't load it. I've tried to rename it to _user_css.html.erb and then it doesn't give the error (just displaying the content). Any ways of telling Rails he has to deal with a CSS partial ?

Comment: In this case you should name it `_user_css.html.erb`. Notice inside `_user_css`, it is just a inline html code for embedding the style tag.

Comment: It tooks me days to understand what you actually meant. Yeah, i'm that stupid. For others users, just use the render :partial with a html template, and within this template, add the <style type="text/css">.
Thanks a lot for your time and your precious help PeterWong ! :)